# Windows Phone Developer Tools January 2011 Update is not being installed

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am new to the windows phone development, and I am struggling to get everything installed related to the windows phone development tools. I had already MS Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU with SP1 installed on my machine (with Windows 7 Enterprise + Windows 7 SP1). I installed the Windows Phone SDK 7.1 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570), and then [Windows Phone Developer Tools RTW](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13890) successfully. But when I tried to open Visual Studio, it said that only a few Visual Studio components had Visual Studio SP1, and in order to open the Visual Studio I had to install the complete Visual Studio SP1. So then I reinstalled the Visual Studio SP1 and the Visual Studio started working fine.

Now I have MS Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU with SP1, Windows Phone SDK 7.1, and Windows Phone Developer Tools RTW installed on my machine, but when I try to install [Windows Phone Developer Tools January 2011 Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23854), following error message is displayed:

"The update patch cannot be installed by the windows installer service because the program to be upgraded may be missing, or the upgrade patch may update a different version of the program. Verify that the program to be upgraded exists on your computer and that you have the correct upgrade patch."

I have verified everything. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try uninstalling the developer tools completely then install dev tools rtw followed by patch and then sdk

Answer (score 0):

I guess something goes wrong with your Visual Studio SP1 installation, so to uninstall all the developer tools and then doing the fresh installation would be the good Idea.

You can do the installation in this sequence..

1. Win 7 SP1
2. Visual Studio
3. Visual Studio SP1
4. WP7 developer tools
5. WP developer tools update

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

That update that is throwing an error is not required. The order of installation is detailed on this page: http://create.msdn.com/en-us/resources/downloads

You want to be installing the SDK 7.1 and then the SDK 7.1.1 update.

There's no need for you to uninstall Visual Studio here.

Regards,
Paul