# Clarification regarding different versions of Windows Phone Development Tools

Tags: windows-phone

Thank you all for reading this question. I am not sure, what is the difference between these two development tools for Windows Phone?

- Windows Phone SDK 7.1 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27570)
- Windows Phone RTW (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13890)

I have searched Google on this issue, but I cannot find a clear explanation. This site 
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328993/windows-phone-developer-tools-january-2011-update-is-not-being-installed)
implies we have to install both the SDK 7.1 and the RTW version. Is that right?
I can see that the SDK 7.1 has more components, but I'm not sure which I need.

I also have a clarification for the 'updates' to these versions. It seems there are two versions as well -

- Windows Phone SDK Update 7.1.1 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29233)
- Windows Phone Developers Tools January Update (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23854)

I know that the Update 7.1.1 is for the SDK 7.1. But what version is the January Update for? The system requirements say it is for the Windows Phone Developer Tools RTM. What is RTM?

Thanks!

Comment: `RTM` is **R**elease **T**o **M**arket. This means that product is considered as finalized

Comment: So, is the SDK 7.1 the RTM version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steve B is right. If you are looking to install the tools, you should install the Windows Phone SDK 8.0 which supports building apps for 7.8 and 8.0. It is free and comes with free version of Visual Studio 2012 express edition. If you already have Visual Studio 2012 Professional or higher, the SDK templates and tools are integrated into your existing installation of Visual Studio.
Windows Phone 8 app development is supported only on 64-bit Windows 8 Pro or higher. You can't develop Windows Phone 8 apps on Windows 7, on Windows Server 2008, or on Windows Server 2012. The last fact you need to be aware of is the system requirements for running the emulator. Windows Phone 8 Emulator runs as a virtual machine on Hyper-V, the virtualization technology for Windows 8. To run the emulator, your computer must meet the requirements to run Hyper-V outlined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I believe the RTM version is the version of the SDK for the first WP devices. The 7.1 has superseeded the RTM version (when the Mango update was released), and the 7.1.1 is an update of the 7.1 (this update allows to target the low memory devices).

That means you have to install the 7.1, then the 7.1.1 to get the latest version. Read this page for more help: https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk

Answer (score 0):

Steve B
RTM is NOT abbrev. for "Release To Market".

RTM=Release to Manufacturer

Best regards

Comment: Thanks to all who answered :)